# NotSerializableException: org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeLogger

Tags: java, serialization, transient

I am using Java 7 with Struts 1.  I have a Java object that I serialise, which results in an error:

> NotSerializableException: org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeLogger

Code:

```
byte[] serializedTravelRequisitionForm = org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.serialize(travelRequisitionForm);
```

**Question**

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

More info:

The `travelRequisitionForm` is a very large object. It extends `ActionForm` (struts).

It does have a logger:

```
private transient Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TravelRequisitionForm.class);
```

But as you can see, I have made it `transient`.  I have also made all `Logger`'s that are in the child objects `transient`.

I haven't included a copy of the `TravelRequisitionForm` here because it is very large and contains many other objects. So I guess that makes it a bit difficult to diagnose the problem, but does anyone have any idea what I can look out for?

When debugging in the `SerializationHelper`, it gets a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` on this line: `out.writeObject(obj);`

Comment: We need to see the code as a whole so we can see where it is occurring.

Comment: The `TravelRequisitionForm` is 3102 lines long. How can I display it?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point. Have you tried debugging it with JDB? Try doing that and see if that assists you. You should share the results here as well as any affected areas of your own code where it occurs.